# Load Container Html Wrapper Without Child

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

Is it possible to load a container with html tag and class without any content? From what I have seen if there are no blocks placed inside a container it does not load.

Is there a method of adding any attributes or concise content that will make it display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with it as it isn't very clean but you could try loading an empty template. This would give you your container without having to actually render anything on the front end.

**Example**

```
<container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="empty.template" as="emptyTemplate" template="Path_To::template.phtml" />
</container>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I first thought of and seems to be the only thing that works, however you have inspired me. What about loading an empty jsLayout / UI crazy thing... ideally without throwing any errors.

Comment: However, that's less clean but it saves having to create directories and files...

Comment: It's worth a try but like you say it isn't any better, providing you name the template so anybody can see it's actually empty I don't think it's THAT bad. Maybe throw in a comment in there to.

Comment: You may even be able to leave out the `as` and `template` attributes.

Comment: Please could I ask why you did that is there something I'm missing there?

Comment: I haven't tried it, I'm thinking you might not even need to create the template file. Maybe having a block nested in the container is enough to force it to render.